# When is __init__.py in a module executed?

Tags: python, module

Based on this post: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for), I know that `__init__.py` in a module has two functions: 1) make the directory into a package so that the module can be imported. 2) do some necessary initialization job, if any. My question is when this `__init__.py` is executed? Every time the module is imported into a module? Or there is something like a shared library in the memory so that this `__init__.py` is only executed once in the whole application?
Further, I do not find good resources on how python interpreter executes python code, any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Use backticks for inline code formatting. \`\_\_init\_\_.py\` becomes `__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init__.py` is executed when imported on the first time. The latter imports in an application lifetime always loads from cache file.

Comment: "The latter imports in an application lifetime always loads from cache" ...unless reloaded (for example, via `importlib.reload`.